# Glide image loadig error

Tags: android

I'm using *Glide* to load my images from *drawable*. But some images but sometimes Glide doesn't load the images.
My code:

.java:

```
public ImageButton home_ib19;
public ImageButton home_ib20;

home_ib19 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib19);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_split)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib19);

    home_ib20 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib20);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_the_red_turtle)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib20);
```

(From 1 to 18 it works fine, I made with the same method, but with these 2, the image is doesn't load)

.xml:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib19"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/home_ib16"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_ib16"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib20"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/home_ib18"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And you can see all my *ImageButton* in a RelativeLayout that's in a *ScrollView*.

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: make sure you have the same name on your drawable folder: `moviep_the_red_turtle` and `moviep_split`

Comment: nope, there is no any error in logcat, and i have the same name on the drawable.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask